# carousel not working - bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot change from first picture into a second one and it doesn't slide automatically between them either. What am I doing wrong? So basically I want to be able to manually slide to change picture to next one and if I don't, it will slide automatically after some time. Anyone care to have a look and tell me what is wrong with this code? Also for some reason when I try to load jquery first, I get an error in console saying:

> bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires
>   jQuery(…)

My code:

```
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/2.jpeg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add jQuery **before** you add bootstrap javascript.

E.g.:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I did however I am getting an error message saying it's undefined `<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`